# Building VLC-Qt library from sources

Tags: qt, cmake, mingw, vlc, vlc-qt

**I've got:**

1. Sources of vlc-qt lib: https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt
2. Example (from the same author): https://github.com/vlc-qt/examples/tree/master/simple-player
3. Qt 5.14, MinGW32/Mingw_w64, cmake-gui

**The purpose:**

To build the example.

**The problem:**

I'm building library using cmake-gui (with no errors), mingw32-make (no errors), but mingw32-make install gives me an error in

```
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "C:/Users/SALEM/Desktop/projects/Qt/_libs/vlc-qt/libvlc-headers/include/vlc/libvlc.dll".
```

I suppose, the problem could be with `LIBVLCCORE_LIBRARY="B:/ProgramFiles/VLC/libvlccore.dll"`, `LIBVLC_INCLUDE_DIR= "C:/Users/SALEM/Desktop/projects/Qt/_libs/vlc-qt/libvlc-headers/include/vlc"` or `LIBVLC_LIBRARY="B:/ProgramFiles/VLC/libvlc.dll"` configuration... actual git repository wasn't provided with libvlc.dll and libvlccore.dll, so I've downloaded VLC player and got this dll's from it, and I'm not sure for headers either.

Comment: Why CMake are looking for dll file in include directory? Could you give a full output of your console including your commands? Also something tells me that LIBVLC_INCLUDE_DIR should be C:/Users/SALEM/Desktop/projects/Qt/_libs/vlc-qt/libvlc-headers/include

Comment: @DaszuOne, "Why CMake are looking for dll file in include directory?" - that's the biggest question for me either! The Makefile is made by cmake-gui, than i do 'mingw32-make' command (it completes without any errors) and 'mingw32-make install' (the last few strings):
[100%] Built target Test_WidgetsPlayer
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/SALEM/Desktop/projects/Qt/_libs/vlc-qt/build'
-- Install configuration: "Debug"
"--------THE ERROR IS HERE-------"
"C:/Users/SALEM/Desktop/projects/Qt/_libs/vlc-qt/libvlc-headers/include " - contains nothing but subdirectory "vlc"